# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll - Timed out

Tags: c#, webclient, webrequest

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll Additional information: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.

Being caused by:  `using (System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())`

```
public string HttpGet(string URI)
{
    System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
    req.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(new Uri("http://google.com")), false); //true means no proxy
    using (System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        string value = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        return value;
    }
}
```

- This works when it's called the first time and keeps working if I call the function every 1-2 seconds.
- ...However if I run the function once (or more), and then wait 5 seconds and run it again the program freezes and I get the error message above. I've tried adding `req.Timeout = 9999999;` or whatever but it still produced the same error.

What can be causing this timeout and how could I go about fixing it?

File that's being called:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/PHP Files/Computing Project - Website/ICTeacher/GeneralFunctions/functions.php');
connect_to_database();

$query = $_GET["query"];
$password = $_GET["password"];


if ($password == "X") {
    if (strpos($query, 'SELECT') !== false) {
            $query_result = mysql_query($query);
    if (mysql_num_rows($query_result) != 0) {
            for ($x=0; $x <= mysql_num_rows($query_result); $x++) {
                echo mysql_result($query_result, $x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would wrap your StreamReader in a `using` statement to make sure everything gets disposed.

Comment: Didn't seem to help, same error being thrown by `System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse()`. Why would putting one around the StreamReader help when the `System.Net.WebResponse` line is causing the error?

Comment: I'm not sure - I wasn't really suggesting this would fix it, it's just a best practice to wrap things that implement IDisposable in using statements :)

Comment: Ok, I'll put that in there. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting these properties on the `WebRequest` : `request.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;`
`request.KeepAlive = true;`

Comment: @pep, It's software to run in school which has to go through the school proxy. So to run SQL queries in MySQL they have to go through a PHP script and then return the value to C#.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll `req.keepAlive` doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @MatWhiteside one thought is that you could be getting throttled by the proxy itself, it's possible the proxy has that protection to prevent someone from essentially DDOS'ing the system.

Comment: @pep I probably should have mentioned at the moment, I'm developing this at home so not going through a proxy. The proxy is there for when I need to test it in college. Just tried changing the WebProxy line to say that I'm not using a proxy and still getting the same error, so I don't think it's that.

Comment: In that case, if it isn't the proxy, the next thing I'd look at is the URL you are requesting and think about whether that particular URL is causing the issue. This is pretty vanilla web request code - nothing fancy about it. I put it in a dotnetfiddle with the proxy commented out and 20 requests to Google complete fine. https://dotnetfiddle.net/1IUirS

Comment: @pep The URL is the same every time so I don't think it's that either. However, when I replaced the URL for google in my program, it didn't show the error any more. I have edited the post to show the contents of the file it's connecting to. It must be something here causing a problem?